# How to use ALSA instead of pulseaudio without uninstalling pulseaudio?

Tags: sound, uninstall, indicator, pulseaudio, alsa

So when pulseaudio is installed on my computer, there is no sound. However, if I uninstall pulseaudio, the ubuntu sound indicator has to be uninstalled too. How can I use ALSA by default without having pulseaudio uninstalled? Or, how can I uninstall pulseaudio without uninstalling the sound-indicator?

Answer (score 3):

Open your terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install gconf-editor
```

Then

```
gconftool-2 --type string --set /system/gstreamer/0.10/default/audiosink "alsasink"
gconftool-2 --type string --set /system/gstreamer/0.10/default/musicaudiosink "alsasink"
```

If you want to enable it for Audio/Video Conf also then

```
gconftool-2 --type string --set /system/gstreamer/0.10/default/chataudiosink "alsasink"
```

[for more information & Indeed credit too.](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/03/how-to-switch-to-alsa-or-oss-instead-of.html)

Comment: After trying this on ubuntu 13.10, pulseaudio is still running, and there is no sound.

Comment: ok do one thing Purge pulse audio. don't worry about notification sound applet.  by having gnome alsa mixer installation we can get it back

Comment: so how do you get indicator-sound back without installing pulse audio?

Comment: http://howto.blbosti.com/2010/04/ubuntu-make-alsa-default-instead-of-pulseaudio/

Comment: No, I want specificity, the indicator sound app back.